# Combine DataView and Carousel

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile, sencha-touch

Is there a way in Sencha Touch to create a DataView that loads data from a store and displays it as a Carousel (or at least behaves as a panel with `layout: 'card'`), where each item is an entry from the store? Obviously, that means that the number of items is always different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example posted by me:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?148378-Dynamic-Carousel-how-to-push-thumbnails-12-per-page-Examples-included

At the moment I am stuck getting the thumbnails split 12 per page instead of all on one carousel.

:-)

Comment: Thank you! [This tutorial link](http://superdit.com/2011/08/20/create-image-gallery-using-sencha-touch/) from your post helped me get what I wanted.